# Check 2G network

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm writing a broadcast receiver that listens to connectivity changes.

My goal is to check if the 2g network is available (wether there is wifi or not).

I've been reading several articles and rewriting my class but can't get to a proper result...

Any help would be great...

Comment: please post your code that is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually care about only being on 2G, this will work.

```
private boolean is2gNetwork() {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo network = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    // Check we're connected with a mobile network
    if (null != network && network.isConnectedOrConnecting()
            && network.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {

        // Check we're on GPRS or EDGE
        final int subType = network.getSubtype();
        return subType == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE
                || subType == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was struggling with !

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getActiveNetworkInfo()` method of [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
   ConnectivityManager con = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (con != null) {
    NetworkInfo info = con.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null && (info.isAvailable() || !info .isConnected())) {
    // do your code part
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  public void CheckStatus() {               

    ConnectivityManager connectionstate = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo network = connectionstate.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 

    if (network != null && network.isConnected() == true) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
    } else {            
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

        .show();         
    }
}
```